# kendo local and remote datasource

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am integrating with the spotfire web player, when I select rows I can trap the event and send the rows to my datasource, however, when I save I'd like to call a service. Is there a way to combine local data source and remote?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by combine local data and remote?

**Variant 1**: You can use dataSource.data - to set the initial records used. And define separate transport that will be used for future requests (after the initial one)

**Variant 2**: You can define the dataSource.transport.read as function and thus perform the binding on your own (allowing you to fetch the data either from local source or from remote service)

**Variant 3**: You can use dataSource.data method to set the records after the Grid is initialized.

All those configurations/settings are listed in the [API](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource) reference.

Comment: Thank you very muck. Variant 2 worked like a charm, for those who are looking to do the same thing my read function looks like this:                            transport: {
                                read:   function(options) {
     options.success(myArrayeData); // where data is the local data array
        },