# KendoUI grid - is it possible to have initial data with remote datasource?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using KendoUI grid widget with the following settings:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: [
                           { id: 1, title: "foo" },
                           { id: 2, title: "bar" }],
                    transport: {
                        read: "/GetList"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        type: "json",
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                Title: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                height: 430,
                columns: [{
                    field: "Title"
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The problem is, that if `transport` property of the `dataSource` is present, the `data` property seems to be ignored (an additional GET request is performed instead).
Is there any way to tell the grid (dataSource) to display initial data but still load remote data when e.g., using pagination or sorting/filtering?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I've already some server-side code that renders views with initial data. Secondly, to avoid the second http request(but this actually doesn't play an important part).

Comment: Huh?  You're trying to populate the grid with "data" and at the same time you call GetList, which is populating the grid with data.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm trying to use some "default" data, but call server methods when something is changed (user goes to another page, applies a filter, and so on). My code is definitely incorrect, but I've not found any example for it yet, that's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior (initial to be from data) and then on to perform ajax is supported only when using the MVC wrappers and their aspnetmvc-ajax transport. Other way it is like you described.

If you really need it you can implement such conditional logic by specifying the ajax transport options as function. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916097/kendo-local-and-remote-datasource).

[Here](http://trykendoui.telerik.com/Otey/3) is an example.